# Would infinite time elapse relative to an outside observer if an object was completely at rest?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, time-dilation

Here's my reasoning... time dilation due to velocity: t'=t√(1-v^2)  v expressed as a % of the speed of light. If you are moving through distance at the speed of light, to an observer at rest relative to you, zero time has elapsed. So if you are at complete rest (no particle movement at all) is infinite time elapsing to you relative to an observer? Would infinite time, mean that you would witness the end of the universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning seems to be that because $\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\to \infty$ when $v\to 1$, it must be the case that $\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\to 0$ as $v\to 0$. But in fact when $v=0$ we have
$$
\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-0^2}} = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1}} = \frac{t}{{1}} = t.
$$
So time does not pass infinitely rapidly but instead passes at exactly its normal rate, as measured by a clock attached to the stationary observer. One should hope that this would be the case!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion. First of all, there is no such thing as a concept of absolute or "complete" rest. Everything is moving in a different inertial frame. Second, time dilation works the other way around from what you described. You would be more likely to witness the end of the universe if you were travelling at the speed of light because one second for you would be infinitely many seconds for everyone else. If there were an absolute rest and you were at it, then one second for you would be shorter than one second for everyone else. So your life would be over very quickly compared to the normal lifespan of humans.

But since there is no absolute rest, that is mostly irrelevant. The most "at rest" you can be is what you are now. You can never go on a trip and return to Earth having aged more than Earth

Answer (score 1):

As stated by fellows such as Albert Einstein, Brian Greene, etc, all objects are constantly moving at the speed of light within that 4 dimensional environment known as Space-Time. All that can be done is change the direction of that constant motion within that environment known as Space-Time.

Thus if your direction of travel at the speed of light was across just Space, then you would be at a standstill in time. And, if you were at a standstill in space, then your constant motion would be across the dimension of time instead (also at the speed of light).

Thus the maximum speed at which you can move across the dimension of time is at the speed of light, thus not at an infinite speed.

Answer (score -2):

Yes -  if the object is remaining an infinite time in its place. By the way, the object belongs to the same inertial reference frame as the observer.